# Setting child tag properties in a repeater control

Tags: javascript, css, repeater, onmouseover, onmouseout

I have a repeater control to show user comments. Comments are kept in a div tag, and inside that div tag, there are other tags also. I assigned a hover property to parent tag to make a child div tag visible on mouseover. When I run the code, the hover property works only the first comment in the repeater. If mouse is kept over other comments, the hover property works for the first comment again. Here is my html code
`

```
        <ItemTemplate>

        <div id="divComnt" class="Dcomment span9" onmouseover="MouseOver_Comment()" onmouseout="MouseOut_Comment()">  
               <div class="date" >Posted at <%#Eval("DateAdded")%></div>
               <br/>
               <p><%# Eval("Comment") %> </p>
               <br/>
                <%--reply buttons--%>
                <div id="Div_replyLinks" class="bottom pull-left replyLink" style="margin:3px 1px 3px 1px">

                <a href="#" title="Katılıyorum"><i class=" icon-thumbs-up"></i> </a>
                <a href="#" title="Katılmıyorum"><i class=" icon-thumbs-down"></i> </a>
                <a href="#" title="Bence..."><i class="icon-comment"></i> </a>

              </div>
            </div>
            </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:Repeater>`
```

And here is the javascript

```
function MouseOut_Comment() {
        var div = document.getElementById("Div_replyLinks");
        div.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    function MouseOver_Comment() {

        var div = document.getElementById("Div_replyLinks").;
        div.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
```

And here is [link](https://fbcdn-sphotos-b-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/1234880_517875051623368_522993819_n.jpg) for the visual aid.(Unfortunately, I cannot upload an image due to lack of reputation)
As you can see in the image, the active comment div is the second one but the reply button icons are visible in the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I find the way to fix the problem. I used <%#Container.ItemIndex%> as id value of the div whose visibility property I'd like to change. Then send the <%#Container.ItemIndex%> as argument of the java functions

Here is the code

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RptComments" runat="server"  >   

        <ItemTemplate>

        <div id="DivComnt" class="Dcomment span9" onmouseover="MouseOver_Comment('<%#Container.ItemIndex%>')" onmouseout="MouseOut_Comment('<%#Container.ItemIndex%>')">  
               <div class="date" >Posted at <%#Eval("DateAdded")%></div>
               <br />
               <p style="margin:2px 5px 2px 5px"><%# Eval("Comment") %> </p>
               <br />
               <%--reply buttons--%>
               <div id="<%#Container.ItemIndex%>" class="bottom pull-right replyLink" style="margin:3px 1px 3px 1px">
                <a href="#" title="Katılıyorum"><i class=" icon-thumbs-up"></i></a>
                <a href="#" title="Katılmıyorum"><i class=" icon-thumbs-down"></i></a>
                <a href="#" title="Bence..."><i class="icon-comment"></i></a>
              </div>
            </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

And here is the java code:

```
function MouseOver_Comment(id) {
        var div = document.getElementById(id);
        div.style.visibility = 'visible';               
    }
    function MouseOut_Comment(id) {
        var div = document.getElementById(id);
        div.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
```